# How often does garbage collector gets called in Xamarin.Android application?

Tags: xamarin.android, garbage-collection, call

I have the following class:

```
public class CurrentOrder
{
    //contains current order values which is global to all application
    public static List<OrderArticleViewModel> listOfOrderArticles = new List<OrderArticleViewModel>();
    public static string orderCustomerName;
    public static string orderCustomerId;
    public static string orderNumber;
    public static string orderDateAndHour;
    public static DateTime executionOrderDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

    private CurrentOrder()
    {
    }

}
```

I use its fields throughout the whole application as global variables for example like that: `CurrentOrder.orderNumber` . When I am on certain activity and press the back button I want to clear all class fields values and I am doing it like that:

```
CurrentOrder.listOfOrderArticles = new List<OrderArticleViewModel>();
CurrentOrder.orderCustomerName = null;
CurrentOrder.orderCustomerId = null;
CurrentOrder.orderNumber = null;
CurrentOrder.orderDateAndHour = null;
CurrentOrder.executionOrderDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
```

But as far as I know the value of these fields stays in memory, the only thing is now my variables point to another place. If I click the back button 1000 times I will have 1000 times the fields in the memory nothing referencing them. I've heard that the garbage collector takes care to destroy the values that nothing is pointing at them but how often that occurs? Is it posible to press back button 100 times without the garbage collector cleaning?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're worrying about? I.e. why do you think it would be bad that clicking the button 100 times might possibly not clean some objects?

Comment: I don't know if it will clean them that's why I'm asking. If it cleans them every time I click the back button it will be the best thing. But if it's not cleaning it so often how often does it clean them? So I know if the app will fill the memory.

Comment: @ProfileForStack4, have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no fixed time interval between garbage collections. Garbage collector called based upon the size of the remaining allocatable memory. Both c# and java are object-oriented language, so we don't need to allocate and release memory manually like c/c++.

Garbage collector will help developer to release memory. Xamarin.Android is using c# language, so it needs CLR to help process to manage memory([Native Android based on ART and Dalvik](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/)).

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals#conditions-for-a-garbage-collection) are conditions that when the GC will be called:

> Garbage collection occurs when one of the following conditions is true:
>
> 1.The system has low physical memory. This is detected by either the low memory notification from the OS or low memory indicated by the host.
>
> 2.The memory that is used by allocated objects on the managed heap surpasses an acceptable threshold. This threshold is continuously adjusted as the process runs.
>
> 3.The GC.Collect method is called. In almost all cases, you do not have to call this method, because the garbage collector runs continuously. This method is primarily used for unique situations and testing.

And I think [memory churn](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory.html#churn) will prove that GC called doesn't have a fixed interval.

About your question:

> Is it posible to press back button 100 times without the garbage collector cleaning?

It is based on your Android system environment( Your app is foreground or background? Is there enough memory?). But it will be gc finally.

So, about memory question, I think the memory leak and OOM( mainly due to Bitmap) should be got more attention. And memory churn also should be avoid, because it will effect Android render([UI Performance](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/performance.html)).